# How do I get the ID of an event on eventClick?

Tags: fullcalendar

My question is pretty straightforward: I want to load a details page from the database on eventClick. So I just need to know how to access the event attributes on the click.

If my question is in any way ambiguous, please let me know and I'll clarify.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) function returns the original event and it will preserve the attributes you've set (unless they have the same key as something used internally).

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            myId: 123
        }
        // other events here
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.myId) {
            alert(myId);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

For version 5
Source : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + info.view.type);

    // change the border color just for fun
    info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 5.11.3, You can do it like this.

First, you have to set **`id`** to an event

```
events: [
         {
           id: 1,
           title: "All Day Event",
           start: "2020-09-01",
           color: '#FF0000',
          },
        ],
```

Then you can access it by with event **`object.event.id`**

```
eventClick: function (info) {
  alert('Event: ' + info.event.id);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also pass in **info** as a parameter to get other values from calendar

```
        eventClick: (info)=> {
            alert(info.id); //ID
            var eventTitle = info.title; //TITLE
            var eventVenue = info.venue; //VENUE
            var eventDescription = info.description; //DESCRIPTION
}
```