# how do i get the id of an event on eventclick in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-9

I can display data from the database in fullcalendar with jquery ajax but am still confused if a certain event is clicked it can display more detailed information

i'm still confused if a certain event is clicked it can display more detailed information

Comment: Take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559060/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-an-event-on-eventclick

Comment: i still confused

Comment: Did you set IDs to your events? Does event.id return anything?

Comment: no, I did lopping from database for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.